# String manipulation in jquery using regex

Tags: jquery, html, regex, performance

I want to extract the url to download a file when user clicks on the image. the url of the image contains the url of the document as `/Image/_Z_/Catalog_doc.jpg`

Then user clicks I call a jQuery function `fetchAndOpen(this)`

In this method I would like to build proper file url i.e. : `/Docs/Catalog.doc`

So basically my issue is image extension (.jpg or .png or any other) second thing I want to remove `/_Z_/` (this is hard coded predefined) and the last thing I want to replace `_` with `.` with the document extension.

Is there any regex or some simple solution of jQuery that can help me i know this can be easily done in javascript with `substring` and `lastIndexOf` methods but i expecting some thing with jquery / regex or other jquery based way out.

INPUT: /Image/*Z*/Catalog_doc.jpg -> OUTPUT: /Docs/Catalog.doc

Thanks.

Comment: Code? http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: INPUT:   /Image/_Z_/Catalog_doc.jpg  -> OUTPUT:   /Docs/Catalog.doc

Comment: Edit your original post with this information and show us any code that you have tried to solve the problem. That will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Given input: /Image/*Z*/Catalog_doc.jpg
Expecting output:  /Docs/Catalog.doc

I simply broke down the process to multiple steps to show a transformation from what you had to what you want.  You can do this in a regular expression if you'd like, but this process was easy to map out and considering it will not happen as a time-intensive process you don't need to worry about the performance of doing multiple steps.

http://jsfiddle.net/cgEt3/

```
var input = '/Image/_Z_/Catalog_doc.jpg';
var output = input.split('/');
output = output[output.length-1]; // get the last part, now output is Catalog_doc.jpg
var ext = output.lastIndexOf('.');
output = output.substring(0, ext); // now just 'catalog_doc';
ext = output.lastIndexOf('_');
output = output.substring(0, ext) + '.' + output.substring(ext+1); // now 'catalog.doc';
output = '/Docs/' + output;

document.write(output);
```